# How to use curl options in RCurl

Tags: r, rcurl

How do you make the following request using the RCurl package?

```
curl -X GET "https://api.youneedabudget.com/v1/budgets/XXXXX/accounts" \
     -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXX"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use the `RCurl` package? Here a solution using the `curl` package:

```
library(curl)
h <- new_handle()
handle_setheaders(h,
                  "accept" = "application/json",
                  "Authorization" = "Bearer XXXXX"
)

req <- curl_fetch_memory("http://httpbin.org/get", handle = h)
jsonlite::prettify(rawToChar(req$content))
#> {
#>     "args": {
#> 
#>     },
#>     "headers": {
#>         "Accept": "application/json",
#>         "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
#>         "Authorization": "Bearer XXXXX",
#>         "Connection": "close",
#>         "Host": "httpbin.org",
#>         "User-Agent": "R (3.5.0 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu x86_64 linux-gnu)"
#>     },
#>     "origin": "77.180.186.114",
#>     "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
#> }
```